# mostrar valores en barras de graficos en google charts

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

tengo un grafico en google chart en el cual quiero que se muestre los valores por cada barra del grafico intente hacerlo pero no funciono, por cierto el tipo de grafico es columnchart.

hasta ahora se ve asi
[image]

quiero que muestre los valores como este grafico por ejemplo
[image]

```js
//========== aca esta el codigo de javascript=====================//

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['', 'Excelente', {
      role: 'annotation'
    }, 'Bueno', {
      role: 'annotation'
    }, 'Regular', {
      role: 'annotation'
    }, 'Deficiente', {
      role: 'annotation'
    }],
    ['Valoración\n general\n de\n la\n atención', 75, '75', 25, '25', 0, '0', 0, '0'],
    ['Trato', 75, '75', 25, '25', 0, '0', 0, '0'],
    ['Tiempo\n de\n espera', 75, '75', 25, '25', 0, '0', 0, '0'],
    ['Información\n clara\n y\n precisa', 75, '75', 25, '25', 0, '0', 0, '0'],

  ]);
  var options = {
    chart: {
      title: 'Comunicación',
      width: 300,
      height: 600,
      legend: 'bottom'
    },

    vAxis: {
      minValue: 0,
      maxValue: 100,
      format: '#\'%\'',
      direction: 1
    },

    hAxis: {
      textStyle: {
        fontSize: 17,
      }
      
    }
  }
};

var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('div0'));

chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
}
```

```html
<div id="div0"></div>
```

Comment: @Rubén si esa linea de want era un comentario que borre y quedo eso. sabes como agregar los valores a cada barra del grafico

Comment: @Rubén ya lo corregi

Comment: @Rubén si sigue sin funcionar, no muestra los valores en cada barra del grafico

Comment: En mi humilde opinión, deberías incluir un [mcve] que genere las gráficas como se muestra en la gráfica y luego indicar lo que has intentado y el error que resulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en las revisiones previas el código en la pregunta no generaba la gráfica<sup>1</sup>, para mostrar cómo agregar las etiquetas a las barras he adaptado uno de los ejemplos en https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart#labeling-bars. Básicamente el "truco" consiste en agregar `{role: 'annotation'}` y los valores correspondientes al `arrayToDataTable`.

---

> En un comentario mencioné que al código de la pregunta le faltan varias cosas. En la parte del HTML, le falta la llamada a loader.js, en la parte de JavaScript le faltan las llamadas google.charts, tiene un `}` que está demás, en el cuerpo de la pregunta  se dice que es ColumnChart pero en el código se llama a una gráfica Bar, entre otros posibles problemas cosas.

---

```js
google.charts.load("current", {packages: ["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Element', 'Density', {role: 'style'}, {role: 'annotation'}],
    ['Copper', 8.94, '#b87333', 'Cu'],
    ['Silver', 10.49, 'silver', 'Ag'],
    ['Gold', 19.30, 'gold', 'Au'],
    ['Platinum', 21.45, 'color: #e5e4e2', 'Pt']
  ]);


  var options = {
    title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
    width: 600,
    height: 200,
    bar: {
      groupWidth: "95%"
    },
    legend: {
      position: "none"
    },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="barchart_values"></div>
```

Comment: arriba en el codigo que puse igual tiene los annotation en el array pero no funciona , lo unico que es diferente es  que en el codigo que muestras tiene el role:style.

Comment: A tu código le faltan varias cosas. En la parte del HTML, le falta la llamada a loader.js, en la parte de JavaScript le faltan las llamadas google.charts, tiene un } que está demás, en el cuerpo de la pregunta dices que es ColumnChart pero en el código llamas a una gráfica Bar, entre otras cosas.

Comment: si eso me di cuenta recien y lo cambie y ahi funciono era el tipo de grafico ya que debia ser columnchar y no bar gracias por la respuesta

Comment: ahora tengo otro problema con los labels de abajo ya que como son muy grandes se ponen con puntitos, sabes como hacer para que se pueda ver todas las letras del labels

Comment: @josemigueljara: Actualiza el código de la pregunta o publica una nueva para entender mejor a que te refieres.

Comment: publicare en  otra pregunta .